# Redis Custom Configuration

Tags: docker, redis

We have build the redis container using the below Dockerfile

```
FROM redis:latest # Copy custom Redis configuration file  
COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf  
EXPOSE 6379  
# Start Redis server with the custom configuration  
CMD [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]
```

redis.conf have below value

`maxclients 50000`

We have build the container and while check inside the redis container using redis-cli and comment used info clients
We have got value as below its not taking the value which we provided in the redis.conf so please post if there any suggestion for the same

`maxclients:10000`

We have tried to update the redis.conf with below value
`maxclients 50000`

Copied the file in redis conf location

Comment: How are you running the container? This works just fine for me without any modifications. Running `CONFIG GET maxclients` on redis-cli outputs the correct number. Also, did you by chance forget to uncomment the line in the config file?

Comment: config file which I added is right its already uncommented inside container this /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf I can see the maxclients  value as 50000 but running the cli comments 

 cat  /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
maxclients 50000
root@instance:/data# redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> auth redis
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> CONFIG GET maxclients
1) "maxclients"
2) "10000"
127.0.0.1:6379>